# Execute SQLCMD.exe from PowerShell in an Azure DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, sqlcmd

I'm porting our deployment infrastructure to Azure DevOps (formerly Visual Studio Team Services), but I've run into an issue I can't find any good solutions to.

We're using EF Core Migrations, and [to work around some unrelated issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10717#issuecomment-358382862) we need to dynamically wrap SQL scripts in SQLCmd, which is easy using PowerShell.

However, when executing our script as a regular PowerShell step in the release pipeline, it fails because SQLCMD.exe is not available. Not so surprising - but I also can't find any documented way of installing it.

Is there a tool installer or some similar ready-made component that will let me execute a PowerShell script that calls out to SQLCMD.exe (via `Invoke-SqlCmd`) as part of an Azure Devops Pipeline? If not, what's the easiest way to accomplish this anyway?

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: Hosted agents (Windows with VS2017).

Comment: @DanielMann: ☝️

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't tried this myself, but are you allowed to install Powershell modules for the current user on a hosted agent? Because Invoke-SqlCmd is part of the [SqlServer module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.0.17199), which can be installed from the Powershell gallery with:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: This is what I eventually ended up doing. It turns out the `sqlcmd.exe` is actually already on the machine (but not in `$env:PATH`) so all I had to do was to install the PS module (and port my script to use it everywhere; I had one direct reference `sqlcmd.exe` that I replaced with `Invoke-SqlCmd`...). Thanks!

Comment: @TomasAschan I want to add something that might help someone. In my case the system variable was already set and I used `Invoke-Sqlcmd` from the beginning in my script. Nevertheless, the task that uses this cmdlet in Azure Pipeline told me that `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cannot be found. The reason for this was: After installing cmdlet, I did not restart the computer (especially BuildAgent), which is why BuildAgent did not notice that there was a new module for powershell. After the restart everything worked fine.
I used `Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Scope AllUsers` in order to install SqlServer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a package to install the needed tools on the agent, since that is now possible. You could use a [Chocolatey](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jungeriusit.jungit-choco) task to run a package from it

There is an (old) chocolatey package available that you could try: https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=SQLCMD

Can't you use normal sql scripts via one of the available extensions? 
See [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=automagically.ExecuteSqlScript) or [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Damutu.DamutuDatabaseTools)

Ofcourse, using a self-hosted agent could be an option, then you can install anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force -AllowClobber
```

Not sure about `-AllowClobber` though, on my local PC the command complained about something without it and I didn't check on Azure tbh.